# In [comparison] to [diff]

Tags: discussion, tags

So we have the [comparison](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/comparison) tag, with 38 questions which does have a few highly voted posts, but overall is spread out over a broad range of topics, ranging from comparing DVDs to text files, to Ubuntu versions themselves.  There's no wiki nor synonyms.

Meanwhile, we have a very specific tag for [diff](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/diff) utility, which achieves exactly that purpose - comparing the data. If you excuse the pun, should we compare the cons and pros of getting rid of the former, overly broad tag ? Is it easier to make it a synonym of [diff](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/diff) ?

Comment: +1, cleanup [comparison] and then make [comparison] a synonym of [diff]

Comment: Not an expert in Ubuntu and Unix tools in general, but perhaps take care of ['comparison' questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bcomparison%5D+-diff+is%3Aq) that are not related to [tag:diff] tool. Otherwise, [tag:comparison] might be a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and should be burninated instead...

Comment: `Comparison` sounds like the very definition of a meta tag. I say we delete it. But it can't be made a synonym of `diff`! Diff is just one of many tools you can use for comparison, you have things like `diff3`, `cmp`, as well as roll your own scripting solutions.

Comment: Owl-right. So, we have a consensus to delete it then ?

Comment: @terdon can we go ahead and delete it?

Comment: I've untagged most questions with exception of one, and if a mod could do something about it that'd be great

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the comments and upvotes on the question, I've taken a liberty to untag all the questions that were previously tagged with [comparison]. Currently, there is [one remaining post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355012/file-comparison-on-the-command-line) that is locked by moderator so I could not edit that out. Otherwise, the tag is ready for deletion

Update: the tag is deleted